# Why isn't my nginx serving the server block, but just the default?

Tags: nginx

I am attempting to use a serverblock with a default site. But the problem is that my default site is what always loads when I load the url of my serverblock.

I following in my config:

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name domain.org;
            root /home/sites/domain.org;
    }


server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            server_name _;
            server_name_in_redirect off;
            root /home/sites/default;
    }
```

If I hit my domain.org I just end up at the default site, as if it ignores it's server block. What am I missing?

Comment: restart nginx??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're trying to connect to domain.org and not www.domain.org. Set domain.org and the default server to use different server logs and check the log file to see what it is telling you. If it is still serving from default after an nginx restart (not a reload, a full restart), post appropriate sections of the error log and access log, as well as an updated config.